# SAS: Identify the last non missing value by ID

Tags: sas

I have this dataset:

```
data temp;
input ID X;
 datalines;
1 210
1 65
1 8
1 .
1 .
1 .
2 230
2 50
2 .
2 .
2 .
2 .
;
```

I would like to create a new variable Y where it takes the value 1 when it is  the last non missing value in the column X by ID else it takes 0 the result is as follows:

```
ID X    Y
1 210   0
1 65    0
1 8     1
1 .     0
1 .     0
1 .     0
2 230   0
2 50    1
2 .     0
2 .     0
2 .     0
2 .     0
;
```

I have tried this code but it does not give me the desired result:

```
DATA temp;
set temp;
by ID;
retain date ;
IF first.ID  then Y= 0;
if X ne . then Y= 1;
run;
```

Thank you in avance for your help!

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you've tried so far.

Comment: What is your intended output if the last non-missing value appears in multiple rows for the same ID?

Comment: In fact X here is the difference between two date (duration) and I would like to get the closest date for my reference date so the last value (minimum) of the column X (that represent the duration).

Comment: What should the output be if ever a real value occurs after a missing value (unless you can assure us that will never happen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want `Y = 1` for the final non-missing `X` per `id`, even if there are multiple rows with that value for the same ID, then you can try the following:;

```
data want;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until(last.id);
  set temp;
  by ID;
  if not(missing(X)) then last_non_missing = _n_;
end;
do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
  set temp;
  Y = _n_ = last_non_missing;
  output;
end;
drop last_non_missing;
run;
```

Comment: The use of `_n_` is intentional - this saves you having to drop a count variable that's unlikely to be of any use after the data step completes..

Comment: I see, but then it is important to warn the readers you are overwriting the default automatice variable `_n_` and that it is not the observation number anymore.

Answer (score 1):

### Assuming

You want to mark every non missing value, followed by a missing value or by an observation for another ID

### Add an indicator that x is missing.

This will alow `by` processing.

```
data temp_vw / view=temp_vw;
    set temp;
    x_missing = missing(x);
run;
```

*(I made it a view, to reduce disk access, bot that is not essential.)*

### Now use that by processing:

set Y true for each real value of `x`, not followed by another real value of `x` for the same `ID`.

```
data want;
    set temp_vw;
    by id x_missing notsorted;
    y = not x_missing and last.x_missing;
    drop x_missing;
run;
```

*(The `notsorted` option will avoid errors if ever a missing value is followed by a real value.)*

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is

```
PROC SORT DATA=TEMP;
BY ID X;

DATA TWO;
SET TEMP;
BY ID;
Z=LAG(X);
IF FIRST.ID NE 1 THEN DO;
IF X>. AND Z=. THEN Y=1;
ELSE Y=O;
END;

PROC SORT DATA=TWO OUT=FINAL;
BY ID DESCENDING X; 
RUN;
```

Assumes rest of data is like example.

Run interactively and view each data set to be sure it is coming out okay.  Then you can streamline, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

## Assuming

You want to mark only the verry last non missing value per ID

### For each ID, find out which observation that is

I here use the automatic temporary variable `_n_`;

```
data temp_vw / view=temp_vw;
    set temp;
    by id;

    retain last_non_missing;
    if first.id then last_non_missing = .;
    if not missing(x) then last_non_missing = _n_;

    if last.id;
    keep ID last_non_missing;
run;
```

*(I made it a view, to reduce disk access, bot that is not essential.)*

### Now use that by processing:

set Y true for each real value of `x`, not followed by another real value of `x` for the same `ID`;

```
data want;
    merge temp temp_vw;
    by ID;
    y = _n_ = last_non_missing;
    drop last_non_missing;
run;
```